# how can i change mat channel?

Tags: c#, opencv, mat

```
public void searchIMG(Bitmap screen_img, Bitmap find_img)
    {
        //스크린 이미지 선언
        //using (Mat ScreenMat = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(screen_img))
        Mat ScreenMat = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(screen_img);

        //찾을 이미지 선언
        Mat FindMat = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(find_img);
        FindMat.ConvertTo(FindMat, MatType.CV_8UC4);

        //스크린 이미지에서 FindMat 이미지를 찾아라
        using (Mat res = ScreenMat.MatchTemplate(FindMat, TemplateMatchModes.CCoeffNormed))
        {
            //찾은 이미지의 유사도를 담을 더블형 최대 최소 값을 선언합니다.
            double minval, maxval = 0;
            //찾은 이미지의 위치를 담을 포인트형을 선업합니다.
            OpenCvSharp.Point minloc, maxloc;
            //찾은 이미지의 유사도 및 위치 값을 받습니다. 
            Cv2.MinMaxLoc(res, out minval, out maxval, out minloc, out maxloc);
            Debug.WriteLine("찾은 이미지의 유사도 : " + maxval);


            //이미지를 찾았을 경우 클릭이벤트를 발생!!
            int offsetY = 35;
            if (maxval >= 0.8)
            {
                InClick(maxloc.X + FindMat.Width / 2, maxloc.Y + FindMat.Height / 2 - offsetY);
            }
        }
    }
```

First, I'm sorry about my english is not good

when i execute this program then Exception occur like this
[exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSKSK.jpg)

so i do debugging and check the different channel like this
[defferent channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuOJp.jpg)

i think the different (CV_8UC4 with ScreenMat) and (CV_8UC3 with FindMat) occur the exception

so and i want to change FindMat's channel to CV_8UC4

i tried googling and apply FindMat.ConvertTo but not apply

so... i can't find change channel method

so Please help me, how can i change the FindMat channel

and if you want to see full souce then click below

[Fullsource](http://colorscripter.com/s/z8EhVR5)

http://colorscripter.com/s/z8EhVR5

Thank you read my question and plese point out my wrong english too if you can

Comment: to chsnge the number of channels you can either use split and merge functions or cvtColor (e.g. BGR2BGRA if you want to chsnge from 3 channels to 4 channels).

Comment: i found solution the problem is defferent bitmap pixel format
so i insert Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(find_img.Width, find_img.Height,System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb); and solved it!

Comment: Tankyou so much

Answer (score 1):

i found solution!!

the problem is defferent bitmap pixel format 
so i insert

Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(find_img.Width,find_img.Height,System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

and solved it!

```
public void searchIMG(Bitmap screen_img, Bitmap find_img)
    {
        Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(find_img.Width, find_img.Height,System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);


        //스크린 이미지 선언
        //using (Mat ScreenMat = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(screen_img))
        Mat ScreenMat = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(screen_img);

        //찾을 이미지 선언
        Mat FindMat = OpenCvSharp.Extensions.BitmapConverter.ToMat(clone);
        FindMat.ConvertTo(FindMat, MatType.CV_8UC4);
        FindMat.ExtractChannel(1);
        Debug.WriteLine(FindMat.GetType());
        //스크린 이미지에서 FindMat 이미지를 찾아라
        using (Mat res = ScreenMat.MatchTemplate(FindMat, TemplateMatchModes.CCoeffNormed))
        {
            //찾은 이미지의 유사도를 담을 더블형 최대 최소 값을 선언합니다.
            double minval, maxval = 0;
            //찾은 이미지의 위치를 담을 포인트형을 선업합니다.
            OpenCvSharp.Point minloc, maxloc;
            //찾은 이미지의 유사도 및 위치 값을 받습니다. 
            Cv2.MinMaxLoc(res, out minval, out maxval, out minloc, out maxloc);
            Debug.WriteLine("찾은 이미지의 유사도 : " + maxval);


            //이미지를 찾았을 경우 클릭이벤트를 발생!!
            int offsetY = 35;
            if (maxval >= 0.8)
            {
                InClick(maxloc.X + FindMat.Width / 2, maxloc.Y + FindMat.Height / 2 - offsetY);
            }
        }
    }
```